# помогите новичку плз(массивы матрица)

Tags: массивы, матрицы

Необходимо вывести матрицу вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается только так(криво):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался сначала записать массив типа `char`, не смог вывести звездочки. Понимаю что мой способ через строки это явно не самый оптимальный и правильный вариант. Как это вывести не через строки?

**код:**

```
public class Matrix {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 5;
    String mas[][] = {{"*","2", "3", "4", "*"}, {"6","*","8", "*", "10"},     {"11", "12", "*", "14", "15"},{"16","*", "18", "*", "20"}, {"*", "22", "23", "24", "*"}};
            for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < mas[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(mas[i][j]+" ");
        }
            System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создавать массив для этого не нужно. Можно составить формулу. Чтобы вывод был красивый, необходимо отформатировать полученные значения, выводя их функцией `printf`. Так строка или число будут дополнены до 3-х знаков пробелами. Вот как это может выглядеть:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 5;
    // Матрица имеет индексы от 1 до 5 по строкам и столбцам
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
            // Проверка на главную или побочную диагональ
            if(i == j || i == n - j + 1)
                System.out.printf("%3s", "*");
            else
                System.out.printf("%3s", n*(i - 1) + j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Чтобы в вашем решение был правильный вывод, замените строку

```
System.out.print(mas[i][j]+" ");
```

на

```
System.out.printf("%3s", mas[i][j]);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное